# How to open up a tab in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a page in which I create some tabs.

```
function addTab(ticketId, name) {
    $('#pageTab').append(
        $('<li><a href="#'+ticketId+'">'+name+'<button class="close" type="button">×</button></a></li>'));
    $('#pageTabContent').append($('\
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="'+ticketId+'">\
                        here some more html \
                    </div>'));
    $('#page' + ticketId).tab('show');
}
```

When the user wants to open the contents of the tab I open the contents with this code:

```
$("#pageTab").on("click", "a", function (e) {
    openTab(e, this);
});
```

which calls this function:

```
function openTab(e, tabId) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(tabId).tab('show');
}
```

I now want to call this openTab function from a different place, but I actually no idea what this `e` variable does or where it comes from.

Does anybody know how I can call this function and supply that `e` variable? All tips are welcome!

Comment: It's an event handler... `e` is the event object...

Comment: Could you not just call `$("#pageTab").trigger('click')`

Comment: The e variable is the event object. You could trigger a click on your #pageTab a using the trigger method of jquery

Answer (score 1):

`e` is the context of the `event`. Whenever an event occurs (click, scroll, keydown etc.) you get a context object that allows you to get more information about the event. This context object is generated for you.

If you call `openTab` programmatically then you don't have an event. Seeing as you only `preventDefault()` you don't need it anyway. Consider restructuring like this:

```
$("#pageTab").on("click", "a", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // we're handling a click, so we have an event, deal with it here
    openTab(this);
});

function openTab(tabId) {
    $(tabId).tab('show');
}
```

Now you can call:

```
openTab($("#some_tab"));
```

Comment: I followed your advice and now try to run opentab using `openTab(tabId);`, but that doesn't seem to work. Id does run openTab(), but `$(tabId).tab('show');` doesn't seem to open the tab if it is called from within a different function. I don't get any error on the console either, it just doesn't open. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

e looks like an event to me. You don't seem to be using it except with e.preventDefault() so you can either modify the functions to not parse it or modify the openTab() function to check if it's null then you can send it a null when calling the openTab() function.

so you could do this:

```
function openTab(e, tabId) {
    if(e!=null){e.preventDefault();}
    $(tabId).tab('show');
}
```

then call the function like this:

```
openTab(null,tabId);
```

Or modify openTab() to look like this:

```
function openTab(tabId) {
    $(tabId).tab('show');
}
```

and modify all references to openTab() as to not send the e variable so they look like this:

```
openTab(tabId);
```